# How to write a hello world add-in for Win 7 Media Center

Tags: c#, mediacenter, windows-media-center

I want to write a simple hello world add in for Media Center on Windows 7, but I am having problems finding up to date functional documentation.  I found this page: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcreasy/archive/2004/10/12/241449.aspx which looks to be exactly what I need.  I implemented it and some of the interfaces it references are marked as obsolete, and even so when I try to launch it in media center is just pops up a dialog saying "unable to launch addin"

I updated the namespace interfaces from using Microsoft.MediaCenter.AddIn to using Microsoft.MediaCenter.Hosting which looks to be the up to date namespace according to the sdk docs, but I still have the same problem.

registering the assembly with the gac and with RegisterMCEApp both are successful, and I have unregistered and registered from both places in between builds.

I strongly signed the assembly with a .snk file and got the public key token to update the registration.xml

Can anyone either tell me what I am doing wrong or direct me to some up to date tutorial /docs?

Here is the little bit of code I have:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.MediaCenter.Hosting;

namespace MCPluginTakeTwo
{
    public class HelloWorldAddIn: MarshalByRefObject, IAddInModule, IAddInEntryPoint
    {
        public void Initialize(Dictionary<string, object> appInfo, Dictionary<string, object> entryPointInfo)
        {

        }

        public void Uninitialize()
        {

        }

        public void Launch(AddInHost host)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe looking at some open source mc [plugins](http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?query=media%20center%20plugin&ac=1) would help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another getting started tutorial, with some tips for getting started with Visual Studio 2010 (because the SDK only comes with VS 2008 templates).

http://david.gardiner.net.au/2010/10/writing-media-center-application-in.html